# How to get information parameters from kernel after boot loads android?

Tags: fastboot, boot, bootloader, reboot, kernel

when an (Android) bootloader starts loading kernel, it passes some parameters to the kernel (for example `androidboot.verifiedbootstate`, ...),how to get the information whether boot gets successful or failed and it should notifies to the user application?

I have gone through this [article](https://source.android.com/security/verifiedboot/boot-flow#communicating-verified-boot-state-to-users) how it will communicate Verified Boot state to users? it means user application? Is there any sample application to communicate from verified boot state to user as toast message?

Comment: `cat /proc/cmdline`